# Use of would've with if and without if in conditional sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage, conditional-constructions

> 1. It would've been icing on the cake if the shoes were black.
> 2. Black Shoes would've been icing on the cake.

My friend was wearing suit but the shoes were not matching, so I told him **"Black shoes would've been icing on the cake"**.

Did I use the right sentence by any means?

Is there any different between the sentence 1 and sentence 2?

Answer (score 1):

Without any more context about what you intended your friend to feel, I think that your metaphor is not quite right here. The point about icing  is that it makes something that is already good (the cake) even better. But as I read your sentences you are slightly criticising his choice of shoes. So if your friend were beautifully dressed from top to toe, you might say "a rose in your buttonhole would have been icing on the cake."

Comment: Eh, you can use "icing on the cake" ironically.  I have certainly see it so used.